# update statusbar menu on click mac os x cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, menu, statusbar

I've been playing around with a statusbar menu app and what I'd like it to do is to update the content of the menu when it is clicked. I've been able to get everything working on the awakefromnib function and it works as expected. Now i just want to update the menu everytime I click on the status bar. This surely can be done, since it's done in the dropbox statusbar menu and many of the native app statusbar menus. I'm not able to associate a action directly with the click of the menu and I don't want to leave a loop running in the background cause I don't really see a need for it. Any ideas? An alternative would be to have an action associated to a menu item which does not cause the menu to get hidden again. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Just set a delegate for your menu, and implement the `-(void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu` method.

Comment: Sorry, still some edges to iron out, but I got it working! Thanks a lot!